# Нужно ли тире и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, спп, запятые, тире

*А чтобы ты поверил, что мы вернемся, — возьми этот залог.*

Можно ли трактовать это тире как интонационное?

Comment: Попробуйте тире нажатием: Alt (удерживая) и 151.

Comment: Точнее, Alt+0151. Цифры нужно набирать на цифровой клавиатуре справа, а удерживать левую кнопку Alt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, тире здесь передает некоторое движение (на, возьми).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! То есть тире может обозначать сопутствующие речи телодвижения? А если так: А чтобы ты поверил, что я не лгу, — посмотри туда. (предполагается, что "там" будет доказательство слов говорящего.) Здесь движения нет, значит тире безосновательно?

Comment: Я не сказал, что телодвижение — единственное основание для постановки тире. Это просто еще один агрумент в пцилью тире. "Посмотри туда" тоже сопровождается жестом. Но тире возможо и здесь: А чтобы ты поверил, что я не лгу, — приходи завтра на это место.

Answer (score 1):

Трактовать, конечно, можно, но я бы его в принципе не ставил. Фраза звучит гладко, без ярко выраженных интонаций. Все паузы обозначены запятыми. Этого достаточно. Розенталь пишет, что чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен. Иначе говоря, при наличии/отсутствии тире в таких случаях меняется смысл сказанного. В Вашем примере смыл будет одинаков независимо от присутствия тире.

Answer (score 1):

Редактирование: А чтобы **поверить**, что мы вернемся, — возьми этот залог.

(Возьми, чтобы поверить).

Тире, конечно, можно поставить, но предложению не хватает экспрессии, оно какое-то вялое, книжное: повторение союзов чтобы, что...

Хорошо бы его как-то переделать, например: **Возьми этот залог — в знак того, что мы вернемся.** Или: он в знак того, что мы вернемся.